# Dynamically add view in raw item of listview with in scrollview not working android

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

i have one scrollview that is compulsory need it . within scroll view i have one Listview . listview's row item have one framlayout . i am adding nativeexpreesview to fram layout when ad is ready .

now problem is if list have 10 items when ad is not loaded  its works okay but when ad is loaded then it occupy some height because i am adding it to frame layout then scroll view scrolls only height of list that is before ad loaded.

but i want scroll with entire item as well ads

My acivity'slayout is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/svStrategy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_bg"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lytBanner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                android:text="@string/str_use_spells_best"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivBanner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
        </LinearLayout>



        <com.example.SummonersWar.classes.NestedListView
            android:id="@+id/lvStrategy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="10dp"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Row_layout of Nestedlistview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytStrategyRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:weightSum="2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivStrategyIcon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.4"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvStrategyTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:minLines="4"


            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlads"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lytStrategyRow"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fr_adview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am programmatically adding Nativeexpressview to framlayout when ads is loaded.

My nestedlistview below

```
public class NestedListView extends ListView implements OnScrollListener // OnTouchListener
{

    private int listViewTouchAction;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE = 100;

    public NestedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        listViewTouchAction = -1;
        setOnScrollListener(this);
        // setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (getAdapter() != null
                && getAdapter().getCount() > MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE) {
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                scrollBy(0, -1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int newHeight = 0;
        final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = getAdapter();
            if (listAdapter != null && !listAdapter.isEmpty()) {
                int listPosition = 0;
                for (listPosition = 0; listPosition < listAdapter.getCount()
                        && listPosition < MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE; listPosition++) {
                    View listItem = listAdapter.getView(listPosition, null,
                            this);
                    // now it will not throw a NPE if listItem is a ViewGroup
                    // instance
                    if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup) {
                        listItem.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    }
                    listItem.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                    newHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

                }
                newHeight += getDividerHeight() * listPosition;
                newHeight += getPaddingBottom() + getPaddingTop();
            }
            if ((heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) && (newHeight > heightSize)) {
                if (newHeight > heightSize) {
                    newHeight = heightSize;
                }
            }
        } else {
            newHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), newHeight);

    }}
```

so my problem is scrollview scrolls only height of list when  ads are loaded .so please help me what should i do now for scrolling entire list with ads?

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class VerticalScrollview extends ScrollView {

public VerticalScrollview(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public VerticalScrollview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public VerticalScrollview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            return false; // redirect MotionEvents to ourself

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            return false;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: use can set custom scrollview in your layout file, and it work proper

Comment: have you set in xml file